# Python - dict of lists - for each unique list element find the associated keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary like this

```
D = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4], 'c': [3,4,5]}
```

For each unique element present across all the lists, I want to find the associated dict keys.

The wanted output is thus:

```
out = {1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4: ['b', 'c'], 5: ['c']}
```

How do I do this most efficiently?

EDIT: I need to do this for a large dict with ~100 keys and each list between 50-10000 elements

Comment: That question doesn't seem focused on efficiency, but yes, essentially the same problem. It seems that the most upvoted answer (not the accepted one) works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for k, vals in D.items():
    for val in vals:
        out[val].append(k)

out
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4: ['b', 'c'], 5: ['c']})
```

Alternatively, use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
out = {}

for k, vals in D.items():
    for val in vals:
        out.setdefault(val, []).append(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this dictionary comprehension with a list comprehension:

```
>>> {val: [k for k in D.keys() if val in D[k]] for v in D.values() for val in v}
{1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4: ['b', 'c'], 5: ['c']}
>>>
```

Or you could try this `for` loop:

```
res = {}
for k, val in D.items():
    for v in val:
        if v in res:
            res[v].append(k)
        else:
            res[v] = [k]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4: ['b', 'c'], 5: ['c']}
```

Comment: One-liner, but terrible algorithmically. You shouldn't iterate all keys *and* value lists for every single value list item in this data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use get function:

```
for i,j in D.items():
    for k in j:
        out[k] = out.get(k,[])+[i]
```